# Can't find unit graph, compiling under Mac OS X 10.9.2, Free Pascal 2.6.2

Tags: macos, graph, osx-mavericks, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to perform some tasks in educational purposes and stuck with unit `graph`.

When compiling I'm getting this error:

```
task4.pas(10,11) Fatal: Can't find unit graph used by task4
```

I've been googling for a while and found that `ptcgraph`, `sdlgraph` and `ggigraph` could be used instead. But I didn't get far with it. `ptcgraph` and `ggigraph` were resulting in same error. However, it is better with `sdlgraph`.

But there were couple linking errors:

```
ld: library not found for -sdl
```

And after `brew install sdl`:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc
```

I've got no idea how to install it. So, I'm wondering if there either something I didn't done or something I'm supposed to use instead of `graph` unit.

Comment: I also found `cairo` but can't find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph unit is not available for Mac OS X because no one has implemented it. The source code that gets installed is generic and hence also contains the source code for units that don't work on the current platform (e.g., it also includes the source code for the Win32 rtl).

The sdlgraph unit was once started by someone, but that person unfortunately disappeared after a short while. You can try using it by added "sldgraph" to your uses clause, but it's unlikely that it will work very well. Contributions to make it work better are of course welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wasn't aware of the fact that graph on Mac is only a kind of scaffold.

Comment: I worked on an implementation of sdlgraph for a while here: http://code.google.com/p/sdlgraph Quite a few functions are working, but it is definitely not complete. If someone wants to contribute extra functions and help make the code conform to freepascal standards--let me know and I'll add you to the project.  The most support for functions is found at http://code.google.com/p/sdlgraph/source/browse/trunk/graphio.pas

Answer (score 0):

Graph should be available on Mac OS X. On my machine it is in the path "/usr/local/share/fpcsrc/packages/graph/src/macosx/graph.pp". Please check if your search paths are correctly set.

However, according to the [official documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/graph/) "The unit is provided for compatibility only: It is recommended to use more modern graphical systems."

Comment: With `fpc -vut task4.pas` I can see that it is looking for unit in    `/usr/local/lib/fpc/2.6.2/units/i386-darwin/httpd22/` first and also in  `/usr/local/lib/fpc/2.6.2/units/i386-darwin/graph`. I can see that `/usr/local/lib/fpc/2.6.2/units/i386-darwin/graph` exists, but it is only `sdlgraph` inside.

Comment: The graph package is at `/usr/local/share/fpcsrc/packages/graph/src/macosx/graph.pp`. It is part of the fpcsrc package that is installed with Lazarus. If you use "barebone" FPC rather than Lazarus you can download the fpcsrc package from [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Mac%20OS%20X%20powerpc/Lazarus%201.0.14/fpcsrc-2.6.2.powerpc-macosx.dmg) for PPC-based Macs and from [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Mac%20OS%20X%20i386/Lazarus%201.2/fpcsrc-2.6.2-i386-macosx.dmg) for Intel-based machines.